# Saving multiple gps locations to same firebase real-time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have successfully stored longitudinal and latitudinal coordinates to the Firebase Realtime Database when a button is pressed. The current database overwrites the coordinates if the phone's location changes. However, I would like to append the new coordinates to the database without overwriting the previously saved ones.

I have tried to pass one of the coordinate strings as the child however the database only accepts a-z letters.
There are five separate buttons that each log the user's mood and the location at that mood.

```
btnGreat = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnGreat);
btnGreat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference =  rootNode.getReference("Location");
        String latitude = Latitude.getText().toString();
        String longitude = Longitude.getText().toString();

        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
        reference.child("great").setValue(coordinates);
    }
});
```

coordinates class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    String latitude, longitude;

    public Coordinates() {
    }

    public Coordinates(String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) method, it means that each time you call this method it overrides the data at the existing location. If you want to have different values  for the coordinates under the `great` node, then you should consider using the [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method like this:

```
reference.child("great").push().setValue(coordinates);
```

This will create a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Location
        |
        --- great
             |
             --- $pushedId
             |      |
             |      --- latitude: 1.11
             |      |
             |      --- longitude: 2.22
             |
             --- $pushedId
                    |
                    --- latitude: 3.33
                    |
                    --- longitude: 4.44
```

Then you can simply read the data:

- [How can I store and retrieve latitude and longitude values from Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806355/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-values-from-firebase)